# Extraction operator into non-numeric character

Tags: c++, istringstream

Given an `istringstream`, is it possible to "extract" its contents into a character  *only if the character to be extracted is non-numeric* (i.e. not 0-9)?

For example, this

```
string foo = "+ 2 3";
istringstream iss(foo);

char c;
iss >> skipws >> c;  //Do this only if c would be non-numeric
```

should extract `'+'`, but if `foo` were `"2 + 3"`, it shouldn't extract anything, since the first [non-whitespace] character is `'2'`, which *is* numeric.

To give some context, I need this to make a recursive "normal polish notation" (i.e. prefix notation) parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unget`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget) to put back the character if it is numeric.

```
string foo = "+ 2 3";
istringstream iss(foo);

char c;
iss >> skipws >> c;
if (std::isdigit(c)) iss.unget();
```

Comment: I actually like this answer better than mine, since it simplifies the whitespace handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `istream::peek` to check what the next character will be before extracting it. You can test the result of `peek` against your acceptable range, and if it matches, do the actual extraction.

BTW, if you want to skip whitespace, you'll also need to check for and handle that with `peek()` (by extracting and discarding whitespace characters). Even with `skipws`, `peek()` won't peek past the whitespace.